# "It was day before yesterday" or "It was THE day before yesterday"?

Tags: definite-article, reported-speech

Are both following options are correct? If not, Which of the options is correct?

> Option A: "It was day before yesterday"
>
> Option B: "It was **THE** day before yesterday"?

The same question for

> Option A: "It will be day after tomorrow"
>
> Option B: "It will be **THE** day after tomorrow"

I always used option A till today when I saw the following slide, which mention option B and caused me this doubt.

[image]

Comment: Option "b" is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the definite article since you refer to the specific day *(one before yesterday/one after tomorrow)*.

- It was **the** day before yesterday.
- It will be **the** day after tomorrow.

Comment: The phrase “on a day before yesterday” is an awkward construct that is best avoided. *Yesterday* is too specific for the indefinite article. Something like “on a summer day” or “on a day in November” would be fine.

Comment: @Soverign - I hope you’ll fix  your answer, then, before it starts collecting downvotes.

Comment: However, I often hear, "**On a day before today...**"

Comment: What does "on a day before today" mean? Does it mean *any* day *before* yesterday"?  Well, you might as well say, "two days ago", or "nearly a week ago". Please cite English native speakers' usage of  [*...on a day before yesterday*...](https://www.google.com/search?ei=gPwSWqu0NMK6Ut_3mogN&q=%22on+a+day+before+yesterday%22&oq=%22on+a+day+before+yesterday%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30k1.2057.6116.0.6498.2.2.0.0.0.0.215.364.0j1j1.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.363...0i22i30k1.0.FEnk6MRuhqY).

Comment: @Mari-LouA That actually means "**on some unspecific day before today and not today**", quite easy. "**on a day before yesterday**" means "**on some unspecific day before yesterday and not yesterday**"

Comment: @Mari-LouA I can't understand why you don't know this.

Comment: I said "any" day, which means exactly an unspecific day. Any = one of a thing. Please take a look at the link, there are six examples, in the entire Internet sphere, of a phrase which you said you often hear.

Comment: @Mari-LouA That's odd, cause I remember seeing it in stories and hearing it somewhere. English should definitely use more of those.